# Fault Tolerance and Load Balancing for Spring RMI

Tags: spring

How to do fault tolerance set-up and load balancing using Spring RMI. The JBoss Application server is set-up in clustered mode. The rmi clients make frequent calls; but, spring-rmi bean set-up doesn't allow to put multiple RMI URLs and there also doesn't seem to be  any tags or property for the stub-bean which allows for multiple URLs (skeleton) calls in clustered environment.

Anyone has a clue or done this..please throw some info.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if this isn't too late..have a look at

[spring-remoting-cluster](http://code.google.com/p/spring-remoting-cluster/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.